# Same Promise returns different types of parsed JSON value (as an object and as a raw string)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a typescript method that returns a `Promise` of a request for a specific configuration file.
Sometimes I will need the same file in different parts of my application, and since the files are static, I want to avoid duplicated http requests for the same file.

I tried to do this by storing the requests in an array of a custom type `HttpRequestObservable`, that is composed by an url (the request url) and an observable for the request.

The `getConfiguration` method will check if the request is already in the array, if it is, it will return the stored `Observable` converted to a `Promise`,  if it isn't, it will create a new `Observable`, store it in the array and return it.

The problem is, when I return an already created `Observable` from the array, the value emitted is of type `string` instead of `Object`

```
export interface IHttpRequestObservable {
    url: string;
    observable: Observable<any>;
}

export class SettingsService {

     private _httpRequestsObservables = new Array<IHttpRequestObservable>();

     private getConfiguration(folder: string, file: string): Promise<any> {
            const url = `/dist/assets/configurations/${folder}/${file}.json`;

            if (this._httpRequestsObservables .some(x => x.url === url)) {
                return this._httpRequestsObservables .filter(x => x.url === url)[0].observable.toPromise();
            }
            else {
                const observable = this.httpClient.get<any>(url);
                this._httpRequestsObservables .push({ url: url, observable: observable });
                return observable.toPromise();
            }
        }

    public async test() {
        const firstRequest = await this.getConfiguration('global', 'settings');
        const secondRequest = await this.getConfiguration('global', 'settings');
        console.log('first request:');
        console.log(firstRequest);
        console.log('second request:');
        console.log(secondRequest);
    }
}
```

When I call the `test()` method, this is the output:

[image: output]

The `firstRequest` is a javascript object while the `secondRequest` is just a string.

Why is the `secondRequest` not an object?

Comment: If you comment out the first log, then what you get? and next when you comment out the second log, then what you get? are both the outputs same.

Comment: @palaѕн I've updated my question to make the output more clear.

Comment: @RafaelDuarte: Do you have to arrays? `_httpRequestsObservers` and `this._httpRequestsObservables`?

Comment: @xyz I had a typo there, it's fixed now

Comment: @RafaelDuarte Replication of your issue over https://stackblitz.com/ would be helpful, otherwise, I don't see why you see stored ones as string

Comment: did you try modifying the http get to this.httpClient.get<any>(url,{responseType:'json'})?

Comment: The default value for responseType is 'json' so that wouldn't be needed